# redirection not happening without refresh page (php+jqmobile)

Tags: php, jquery-mobile

I have got a html like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html manifest="">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="Find">
    <div data-theme="b" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h3>test</h3>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <form action="handler.php" id="findForm" >
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                    <label for="textinputf1"> keyword: </label> <input id="textinputf1"  name="keyword" placeholder="" value="" type="text" />
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <input type= "submit" data-theme="g" value="Find" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="Results">
    <div data-theme="b" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h3>Results</h3>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true">
            <li><a href="">HEllo</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Bye</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>​
```

a handler.php like this:

```
<?php 
//...
if( let's say false ) {
    header("location:.");
}else{
    header("location:./#Results");
    //header("Refresh:0;url=/application/test/#Results");   
}
```

with header+refresh or  with header+location, when I submit the form, I see this in url bar:
    .../handler.php?keyword=test

but I'm not redirected, and if I refresh the page (hit enter from the url bar or F5) THEN I get to the #Results, but not automatically

any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jquery mobile probably uses ajax to handle your form. You should switch of ajax handling for the form

[jQuery Mobile form sample](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/forms/forms-sample.html)

Also put a space in your location

```
Location: whereyouwanttogo
```

Comment: but I like the way it's done with <form action="my.php" because it binds enter key to buttons, natively

Comment: that will remain, you only need to switch off the ajax handling for forms addding

    data-ajax="false" 

to the form should be sufficient

Comment: yes data-ajax="false" makes it,  but wait, even with that, I'm still able to go back and go forward in my browser history, so what was is the advantage of Ajax?

Comment: In simple words, sending a form with ajax would send the data to the server without needing to load the entire page.

Comment: last q, header("Location: ./#somewhere"); is not working if the it's loaded with ajax

Comment: make it "Location: yourfile.html#somehwere" and don't load it with ajax

Comment: I will try echo '<script language="javascript">location.href="#Results"</script>'; it could work, and keep the advantage of ajax, that reduces bandwidth?

Answer (score 0):

Way to see the passed parameters without refresh is by putting     data-ajax="false"

If you wish to use ajax, do not call urls directly. Call these with AJAX and based on response redirect to #Results with the help of JavaScript.

Comment: with the first case (<form action="r.php" data-ajax="false"> <input type="submit">, It bind enter key to button natively (without any jquery handler), that's why I preferred first solution, but I don't like th efact to do data-ajax="false" and lose ajax